# Android BLE Blood Pressure Monitor app

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, business-process-management

I am new to Android Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) applications. I have a blood pressure (and heart rate) monitor with ISSC chip design with BT5050 HW/SW version. I downloaded Android BluetoothLeGatt sample program, and can see implemented services, including Device information service, and others. I have below questions and will appreciate if someone can provide answers:

1. Which GATT profile/service I use to connect to the BPM server and can send commands, such as START, STOP.
2. I like to know which services do the below UUID refer to:

   - 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455. (Service)
   - 0001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  (Service)
   - 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Characteristic)
   - 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Characteristic)
   - 00002a0-40000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Characteristic)
   - 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Service)
   - 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Characteristic)
   - 0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Characteristic)

     1. Once the device start sending data, which GATT Service I need to read off of?
     2. Is there a way to send query to the device to reply back with supported commands?

Comment: I googled multiple articles, but none of them provided answers to the above queries. Some of the links I already referred to are, https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx, https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers https://developer.bluetooth.org/DevelopmentResources/DevelopmentPlatforms/Pages/Development-Platforms.aspx, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by BPM server?. Do you have a BPM server and want to send data obtained from sensor to it? or you mean BPM Service?

Comment: It seems the 1800 serive is a generic access service  which has all kinds of properties (eg. read, write, writewithoutresponse and so on...)

The characteristics:
2a00 - is device name
2a01 - is appearance like a walk calculator in shoes or similar
2a04 - is preferred connection parameters, i personally have no clue what that is :S 
fffx series seem to be "custom" i think, fff1 char should be write and fff2 should be read characteristics. Tho i might be wrong on this... (could not find official docs on these)